# Proof that a vector space is a subspace by showing it is a span

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I want to show that the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}^3: x=y, y=iz\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. Can we simply say that it is equal to the span of $\begin{pmatrix}iz\\iz\\z\end{pmatrix}$? How can I prove this/explain my solution better?

Comment: You have not defined $z$ though. Pick a set of vectors (in this case, there is just the one) in $\Bbb C^3$, and show that the span of this set equals the set you were given. You're almost there though.

Comment: @ElliotG So would it just be span of $\begin{pmatrix}i\\i\\1\end{pmatrix}$? And how do I prove the span of the set is the one given?

Comment: That would be one possibility. As to proving the set is the span of that vector... you would show that everything in the span of that vector is in the set, and that everything in the set is in the span of that vector: the same way you prove that two sets are equal.